# How to ask if it's opposite day and get a meaningful answer

Tags: logical-deduction

If it's opposite day, every question has to be answered with the opposite answer.

If you don't know if it is opposite day or not, what question could you ask to positively know if it is opposite day?

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Depends on if it's opposite day or not :)

Comment: What if you don't know if the person you're asking is a knight or a knave, and if you don't know what the words for "yes" and "no" are in their language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe just this:

> Is grass green?

Comment: But what if it's dried grass?

Comment: The simplicity here is awesome

Comment: What if they're color blind?

Comment: @EngineerToast what if they don't understand English?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume the intent is that you can't use outside truths and have to ask a question related explicitly and exclusively to what day it is. With that in mind, I would ask:

> If I were to ask you if it was opposite day, what would be your answer?

If it *is* opposite day:

> Their answer to the question of "is it opposite day" would be "no" so, in order to answer *this* question in the spirit of opposites, they would say "yes".

If it is *not* opposite day:

> Their answer to the question of "is it opposite day" would still be "no" but they shall not answer in the spirit of opposite day so they would say simply "no".

Quick Reference:

> If they say "no" then it's not opposite day.
>  If they say "yes" then is *is* opposite day.

Comment: That's the best answer IMO. I first considered suggesting "On the opposite day, do you answer this question by lying?" but it means the same as your sentence.

Comment: I am really not following the logic here.  I don't see any difference between your question, and just simply, "Is it opposite day"?  And so, if it is opposite day, how can they answer yes (they would have to answer the opposite)?

Comment: @seabass2020 Asking the question as I have it requires them to consider two layers of logic instead of one. The answer to Q1: "Is it OD?" is always "No" and everybody knows this. However, the answer to Q2: "What would you say if I asked if it was OD?" is different. On OD, they know the answer to Q1 is "No" and they reply in opposite so they say "Yes" because "Yes" is the opposite of "No". It's the same as lying.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which only refers to whether or not it is opposite day, assuming no outside knowledge:

> "Is either true or not true that today is opposite day?" This is tautologically true, so a yes answer means it <s>is</s> isn't opposite day, and a no answer means it <s>isn't</s> is.

Edit: I got my is and isn't mixed up (maybe it is opposite day!).

Comment: I think the opposite is what you meant. If it's tautologically true, then the answer must be "yes"; only on opposite day would it be permissible to answer "no".

Comment: Elegant! But it seems a little unnecessary to construct tautologically true statements, at least if we are working in a formal logic system where we can ask "Is True true?" where True is the trivially true proposition. There's no nice way of formulating that in normal English though...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasonable rulesets describing such a day. Assuming the answers are always yes/no:

- *Opposite answers*: Every answer has to be the opposite (negation) of what it would have been on a normal day (assuming everybody always tells the truth
  on a normal day).
- *False answers*: Every answer has to be a lie.

The first one is the most literal interpretation of the question. To figure out whether it's *one* of these days, we can simply ask any question to which
we know the answer, such as

> Is 1 + 1 = 2?

If we want to distinguish between opposite and false answers, we can ask

> Is today opposite day?

It turns out that it is equivalent to ask

> Are you lying?

On a normal day, the answer is no, so in opposite answers the answer is yes.
However, in false answers the answer is no (since it is in fact opposite day and so "no" is a lie).

By combining these two questions we can find out if it is a normal day, opposite day with opposite answers or opposite day with false answers. It is not possible to find this out with a single question since we need $\log_2 3 \approx 1.58$ bits of information but a single yes/no answer is only 1 bit of information.

In summary (answers are given in the order Normal day, Opposite answers, False answers):

> Is 1 + 1 = 2? Yes, No, No.
>  Is today opposite day? No, Yes, No.
>  Are you lying? No, Yes, No.

It is interesting to note that the "opposite answers" answer to the last questions is actually self-contradictory: The person answering is saying "I am lying", which cannot be true and cannot be false.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them what is the opposite word for the word "true" ?

> If it is  opposite day they will say true because opposite of true is "false" and opposite of "false" becomes "true".
>
> If it is  not opposite day then there answer is "false".